# Formatting within a string

Tags: java, format

Within a method, I have the following code:

```
s = s + (items[i] + ":" + numItems[i]+" @ "+prices[i]+" cents each.\n");
```

Which outputs:

```
Candy:      5 @ 50 cents each.
Soda:     3 @ 10 cents each.
```

and so on . . .

Within this line, how do I get the 5, 3, etc . . to line up with each other so that it is:

```
Candy:      5 @ 50 cents each.
Soda:       3 @ 10 cents each.
```

This is part of a `toString()` method, so I can't do it with a `System.out.printf`

Comment: See [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), works the same as `printf` but returns a String rather outputting it..

Answer (score 1):

String.format() and the Formatter classes can be used.

Following code will output something like this

```
 /*
 Sample Text    #
     Sample Text#
 */
```

Code

```
 public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  
 }

 public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
     return String.format("%1$" + n + "s", s);  
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(padRight("Sample Text", 15) + "#");
    System.out.println(padLeft("Sample Text", 15) + "#");
 }
```

Some more snippet for formatting

```
 String.format("%5s", "Hi").replace(' ', '*');
 String.format("%-5s", "Bye").replace(' ', '*');
 String.format("%5s", ">5 chars").replace(' ', '*');
```

output:

```
 ***Hi
 Bye**
 >5*chars
```

Apart from this Apache StringUtils API has lot of methods like rightPad, leftPad for doing this.
[Link](http://www.jdocs.com/lang/2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tab character `\t` in your toString()

Heres an example:

```
System.out.println("Candy \t 5");
System.out.println("Soda \t 10");

Candy    5
Soda     10
```

So in your case

```
s = s + (items[i] + ": \t" + numItems[i]+" @ "+prices[i]+" cents each.\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use the \t for inserting a tab.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s = s + (makeFixedLengthString(items[i]) + ":" + numItems[i]+" @ "+prices[i]+" cents each.\n");

public String makeFixedLengthString(String src){
        int len = 15;
        for(int i = len-src.length(); i < len; i++)
            src+=" ";
        return src;
}
```